# Issue With Collision c++

Tags: c++, geometry, collision-detection

I am having a hard time with getting some basic collision to work. I have an image I am bouncing around in different shapes. Currently, I have made rectangle collision work. This was relatively easy since the lines where straight, so I was essentially just keeping the obj in a rect and if it went out of bounds of x1, x2, y1, or y2, I changed the velocity to its opposite.

I am trying to accomplish the same thing inside of a triangle and am  having the hardest time with it. I have done some reading but for some reason the light switch in my brain is not turning on!

so I have a triangle... I have determined the slope by taking (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1); however, I cannot make any progress in using the slope in the programming to cause the collision to register correctly.

I would provide some code but honestly nothing is even close to working lol.

Any advice on how to approach getting an obj to bounce around inside a triangle?

or, how to make an obj bounce off of a / style line?

Comment: What you want is line-line collision detection, since you can break down any polygon into lines. Try googling that

Comment: You should look into the GJK/EPA algorithms. SAT works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending how involved you want to get you might find Game Physics Engine Development helpful. The great thing about this book is that all the source code is available via [GitHub](https://github.com/idmillington/cyclone-physics) and the specific source file for [fine grain collision detection](https://github.com/idmillington/cyclone-physics/blob/master/src/collide_fine.cpp). The code is pretty clean and useable.

Comment: hum, that's awesome. I actually want to look into a physics engine. Although right now it seems a little distant to me considering I still cannot get the line to line collision to work! lol ;) I will check it out though.